# react-dnd: Adding DragSource breaks the default drop functionality of native inputs

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

If I render a component wrapped with `DragSource` then the native input's behavior breaks and I can't drop text into input or text area. If to unmount `DragSource` then native drop works as expected.

Please see a [demo](https://repl.it/@pavel_griza/react-dnd-issue) on repl.it

**Screenshot**
[image: react-dnd-issue]

**The simple way how to reproduce the issue**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

const TextComponent = ({ connectDragSource }) => {
  return connectDragSource(
    <p>DragSource component</p>
  );
}

const source = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return { value: 'Some value' };
  }
};

const collect = (connect) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource()
});

const DnDComponent = DragSource('TEXT', source, collect)(TextComponent);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="react-dnd-component"><DnDComponent /></div>
        <div className="text-to-drop">Select and drop it</div>
        <div className="textareat-to-drop"><textarea /></div>
        <div className="input-to-drop"><input /></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const AppContainer = DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(App);

ReactDOM.render(<AppContainer />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Packages that I use**

```js
"react": "^16.8.2",
"react-dnd": "^7.4.5",
"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^7.4.4",
"react-dom": "^16.8.2",
"react-scripts": "2.1.5"
```

Obviously `react-dnd` catches the event and somehow breaks the default event propagation. Could you please suggest to achieve the default behavior?